# How to read CSV file with different number of columns with Spring Batch

Tags: spring, file, csv, spring-batch

I have a CSV file that doesn't have a fixed number of columns, like this:

```
  col1,col2,col3,col4,col5    
  val1,val2,val3,val4,val5 
  column1,column2,column3
  value1,value2,value3
```

Is there any way to read this kind of CSV file with Spring Batch?

I tried to do this:

```
<bean id="ItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">

    <!-- Read a csv file -->
    <property name="resource" value="classpath:file.csv" />

    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <!-- split it -->
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names"
                        value="col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,column1,column2,column3" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                    <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="myBean" />
                </bean>
            </property>

        </bean>
    </property>

</bean>
```

But the result was this error:

[image: IncorrectTokenCountException stack trace]

Comment: Take a look at the `AbstractLineTokenizer#setStrict(boolean)` (which `DelimitedLineTokenizer` inherits from) and set it to `false`.

Comment: this method don't work :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper` to delegate to the appropriate `LineMapper` implementation per line based on a pattern.  From there, each of your delegates would use a `DelimtedLineTokenizer` and a `FieldSetMapper` to map the line accordingly.

You can read more about this in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper.html

Comment: Thank you very much @Michael

Answer (score 1):

`AbstractLineTokenizer#setStrict(boolean)` in your `DelimitedLineTokenizer` should do the job.

From the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/AbstractLineTokenizer.html#setStrict-boolean-) :

> Public setter for the strict flag. If true (the default) then number
>   of tokens in line must match the number of tokens defined (by Range,
>   columns, etc.) in LineTokenizer. If false then lines with less tokens
>   will be tolerated and padded with empty columns, and lines with more
>   tokens will simply be truncated.

You should change this part of your configuration to:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
    <property name="names" value="col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,column1,column2,column3" />
    <property name="strict" value="false" />
</bean>
```