# Spring-Batch: reading a file multi-format

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm trying to read a txt files using spring batch but my problem is each file has different data.
for example each line of a file correspond to a Class, so for each line i need different  FlatFileItemReader, Tokenizer, and FieldSetMapper.

My file looks like:

```
00|0|56||Class1|25|001|0
02|23|11||Class2|65|ENG|ENG|
02|32|25||Class3|45|0101|FRA|Es|TR
```

I've tried read file that contains same format of data and it works, but I don't know how to do it for file with different format.

```
FlatFileItemReader<Class1> fileReader=new FlatFileItemReader<Class1>();
fileReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("/file.txt"));
DefaultLineMapper<Class1> lineMapper=new DefaultLineMapper<Class1>();
DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer=new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
tokenizer.setDelimiter("|");
lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
fileReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
```

Any help would be appreciated .
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read CSV file with different number of columns with Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45501777/how-to-read-csv-file-with-different-number-of-columns-with-spring-batch)

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine thank you but each line represent an object of class

Comment: That's not an issue. The answer in the question I linked uses a `PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper` which can be used here too with patterns like `*Class1*` and `*Class2*`, etc. But I edited the answer by @Luca Basso Ricci with an example because his answer is correct and he deserves the credit !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a kinda of `CompositeLineMapper` where you store a different `LineMapper` implementation specific for every type of class you need to manage.
This `CompositeLineMapper`, for every line in your file, will look-ahead discriminator column and dispatch to right `LineMapper` implementation.
I can't give you code because I'm not using SB atm,so I left to you the implementation.

**EDIT:** Adding an example of how to classify items

Here is a composite line mapper based on a `Classifier`:

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.LineMapper;
import org.springframework.classify.Classifier;

public class ClassifierCompositeLineMapper implements LineMapper<Object> {

    private Classifier<String, LineMapper<?>> classifier;

    public ClassifierCompositeLineMapper(Classifier<String, LineMapper<?>> classifier) {
        this.classifier = classifier;
    }

    @Override
    public Object mapLine(String line, int lineNumber) throws Exception {
        return classifier.classify(line).mapLine(line, lineNumber);
    }
}
```

And here is how to use it:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import org.springframework.batch.item.file.LineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PassThroughLineMapper;
import org.springframework.classify.Classifier;

public class ClassifierCompositeLineMapperTest {

    private ClassifierCompositeLineMapper compositeLineMapper;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Classifier<String, LineMapper<?>> classifier = new Classifier<String, LineMapper<? extends Object>>() {
            @Override
            public LineMapper<?> classify(String classifiable) {
                if (classifiable.contains("Class1")) {
                    return new Class1LineMapper();
                }

                if (classifiable.contains("Class2")) {
                    return new Class2LineMapper();
                }
                return new PassThroughLineMapper(); // or any other default line mapper
            }
        };
        compositeLineMapper = new ClassifierCompositeLineMapper(classifier);
    }

    @Test
    public void mapLine() throws Exception {
        Object line1 = compositeLineMapper.mapLine("00|0|56||Class1|25|001|0", 1);
        Assert.assertTrue(line1 instanceof Class1);
        Object line2 = compositeLineMapper.mapLine("02|23|11||Class2|65|ENG|ENG|", 2);
        Assert.assertTrue(line2 instanceof Class2);
    }

    static class Class1 {}
    static class Class1LineMapper implements LineMapper<Class1> {

        @Override
        public Class1 mapLine(String line, int lineNumber) throws Exception {
            return new Class1(); // TODO mapping logic
        }
    }

    static class Class2 {}
    static class Class2LineMapper implements LineMapper<Class2> {

        @Override
        public Class2 mapLine(String line, int lineNumber) throws Exception {
            return new Class2(); // TODO mapping logic
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, just I have one more question: when I use FlatFileItemReader, I call it with any class?

Comment: The problem is  which class?

Comment: This answer is correct, and since Luca can't give an example atm, I did it. @LucaBassoRicci please don't hesitate to modify/amend the example if necessary.

Comment: LucaBassoRicci, MahmoudBenHassine  thank you very much, it works, but I found another problem when I call writer, how I specify which class writer to use? I already try CompositeItemWriter but it's not working, do you have any idea? –

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine, thank you very much for your help.
From my perspective, the out-of-the-box solution proposed by @MahmoudBenHassine is better than mine because I didn't know the existence of that component is SB.
Maybe the `PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper` should be added to this answer to offer a complete solution.

Comment: @noor: check `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter`

Comment: I second Luca's comment, to classify items at writing time, `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` is the way to go. These two components (`PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper` and `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter`) are usually used together in combination, here is a similar question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51766820/5019386. Hope this help.

Comment: MahmoudBenHassine, LucaBassoRicci thank you very much it works with ClassifierCompositeItemWriter